# Python / Kivy: Move one button to the position of other button after confirmation

Tags: python, kivy

I want the alpha button to move to the position of the beta button, after confirming first the alpha button and then selecting the position of the beta button.

The different layouts should stay because I need them to be on separate ones. And it should be repeatable with new buttons without needing a new function for each new one.

I know there is quite a lot not right below, but don't know how to solve it.

Thank you for reviewing.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'maximized')

kv = ("""

FloatLayout:
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        TestScreen:

<TestScreen>:
    name: "test_screen"
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            id: beta
            background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.2
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.95, 'center_y':.1}
            on_release: app.beta_active()
            on_release: app.move_to()
                
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            id: alpha
            background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1 
            size_hint: 0.1, 0.2
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.1}
            on_release: app.alpha_active()
""")

class TestScreen(Screen):
    pass

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        kivy_design = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return kivy_design

    def alpha_active(self):
        alpha_pos = self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen("test_screen").ids.alpha.pos_hint
        return alpha_pos

    def beta_active(self):
        beta_pos = self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen("test_screen").ids.beta.pos_hint
        return beta_pos
        
    def move_to(self):
        alpha_pos = beta_pos

TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify your `move_to()` method as:

```
def move_to(self):
    self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen("test_screen").ids.alpha.pos_hint =\
        self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen("test_screen").ids.beta.pos_hint
```

Note that your `alpha_active()` and `beta_active()` methods do not actually do anything. Also, after `move_to()` is run, the `beta` button is still there. It's just underneath the `alpha` Button.